# IIS 7 URL Rewrite - how can i create the rule for 2 similar URLs

Tags: iis, web-config

i've created friendly URLs for a website using the web.config file in IIS 7.5.

i've created a rule for an articles page which looks like this :

```
            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL10" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^articles\.php$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^title=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;id=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="articles/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL10" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^articles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="articles.php?title={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

this works fine.
an example of the friendly URL would look like this : http://www.example.com/articles/name_of_article/2104

now my client wants to add a 'landing page' which will list all of the articles, rather than going directly to an individual article.
they want the link to read http://www.example.com/articles or something very similar.

now i've changed the code on the page articles.php so that if there is no id passed in the querystring, or if the querystring id is 0 then the page will display the article list as required... if there is an id it will show only that specific article.

my question is, how can i write a rule so that it will rewrite the URL correctly
e.g.
    http://www.example.com/articles.php?id=2104&title=name_of_article
    becomes
    http://www.example.com/articles/name_of_article/2104

and
    http://www.example.com/articles.php?id=0
    becomes
    http://www.example.com/articles

only the first part currently works using the rule shown above.